# How to pull active or deactive accounts in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am currently compiling a report for a user and need to be able to pull only active accounts from MSSQL Server 2016. I noticed [dbo].[AccountBase] and [dbo].[Account] doesn't have an obvious column that shows if an account is active/deactive, however you can pull this type of report from the CRM front-end.

Is there a table somewhere that includes this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [statecode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531157.aspx) attribute to filter by `active(0)/in-active(1)` record.

SQL

```
SELECT top 100 *
FROM [dbo].[Account] as account
WHERE account.StateCode = 0 --active accounts
```

FetchXml equivalent:

```
<filter type="and">
  <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
</filter>
```